# converting Excel array formula to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

Hello Everyone
I've got this array formula in excel and I want to merge it in a VBA code but it gives me an error of Unable to set the `FormulaArray` property of the Range class (Error 1004)
Here is the formula after i ammended it in the code

```
"=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(($D$2=$B9)*(E$7>=$D$3)*(E$7<=$D$4)*(NOT(E$6>=1))*(NOT(E$8='الجمعة'))))=1;VLOOKUP($D$5;LeavesTypes;2;0);"""")"
```

and here is the full code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Dim wrk As Workbook, DataSH As Worksheet, CurrentSH As Worksheet
Dim FirstCol As Integer, EmpRow As Integer, EmpID As String
Dim GetEmpRowLoop As Integer, StartingEmpCol As Integer
Dim StartColLoop As Integer, EndingEmpCol As Integer
Dim EndColLoop As Integer
Public Sub Macro1()

    Set wrk = ThisWorkbook
    Set DataSH = wrk.Worksheets("الاجازات ")
    Set CurrentSH = wrk.ActiveSheet

    If CurrentSH.Name = DataSH.Name Then
        MsgBox "Please Navigate to an Active Sheet", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    EmpID = CurrentSH.Range("d2").Value
    
    For GetEmpRowLoop = 9 To CurrentSH.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If CurrentSH.Cells(GetEmpRowLoop, 2).Value = EmpID Then
            EmpRow = GetEmpRowLoop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next GetEmpRowLoop
    
    For StartColLoop = 4 To CurrentSH.Cells(EmpRow, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
        If CurrentSH.Cells(7, StartColLoop).Value = CurrentSH.Range("D3").Value Then
            StartingEmpCol = StartColLoop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next StartColLoop
    
    For EndColLoop = 4 To CurrentSH.Cells(EmpRow, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
        If CurrentSH.Cells(7, EndColLoop).Value = CurrentSH.Range("D4").Value Then
            EndingEmpCol = EndColLoop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next EndColLoop
    
    CurrentSH.Range(Cells(EmpRow, StartingEmpCol), Cells(EmpRow, StartingEmpCol)).FormulaArray = _
    "=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(($D$2=$B9)*(E$7>=$D$3)*(E$7<=$D$4)*(NOT(E$6>=1))*(NOT(E$8='الجمعة'))))=1;VLOOKUP($D$5;LeavesTypes;2;0);"""")"
          
End Sub
```

I'm trying to place whether the formula itself or the result doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to replace the single quotes (') with double quotes ("").  However, you'll need to double up on the quotes...

```
(NOT(E$8=""الجمعة""))
```

By the way, there's no need for `SUMPRODUCT`.  The following should suffice...

```
.Formula = "=IF(($D$2=$B9)*(E$7>=$D$3)*(E$7<=$D$4)*(NOT(E$6>=1))*(NOT(E$8=""الجمعة""))=1;VLOOKUP($D$5;LeavesTypes;2;0);"""")"
```